# Missing Haskell primitive to apply a function to each element of a list successively?

Tags: haskell, combinatorics

In Haskell, it is well known that the `map` primitive can be used to apply a given function to **all** elements of a list:

```
 λ> map toUpper "abcd"
"ABCD"
 λ>
```

While trying to generate all partitions of a finite set (list), the following, similar primitive would be handy:

```
 λ> sap toUpper "abcd"
["Abcd","aBcd","abCd","abcD"]
 λ>
```

with `sap` standing for *successive applications*.
The type signature would be:

```
sap :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

For example, part of the partitions of set "abcd" can be obtained from the partitions of "bcd" by sap'ing them with ('a':).

```
 λ> pbcd = [["b","c","d"],["b","cd"],["bc","d"],["c","bd"],["bcd"]]
 λ> 
 λ> concatMap (sap ('a':)) pbcd
[["ab","c","d"],["b","ac","d"],["b","c","ad"],["ab","cd"],["b","acd"],["abc","d"],["bc","ad"],["ac","bd"],["c","abd"],["abcd"]]
 λ>
```

and the 5 missing partitions can then be obtained by adding 'a' as its own separate singleton.

My problem is that I have been unable to locate such a primitive in the language libraries, and that [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/), given the type signature, returns nothing of interest.

Does such a primitive as `sap` exist somewhere in the Haskell language libraries ???
Or is there a way to write it that is so short and simple that it does not even deserve to be a separate function, putting it below the so-called [*Fairbairn threshold*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Fairbairn_threshold) ?

**Footnote**:
It is possible to write `sap` like this:

```
sap :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [[a]]
sap fn ls = fst  $  foldr  op  ([], [])  ls
   where  op x (ll,tl) = ( ((fn x):tl) : map (x:) ll , x:tl )
```

Essentially you start with `[[fn (last ls)]]` as a seed and then progress leftwards. But this seems pedestrian not simple.

Comment: Why do you call it a "primitive"? It's just a function.

Comment: You might also like to think about `zippers :: [a] -> ([a], a, [a]); zippers = go [] where go b [] = []; go b (h:e) = (b,h,e) : go (h:b) e`. It is a generally useful function that makes a nice component for implementing `sap`.

Comment: As long as we're having fun with this function, I find this to be a pretty clear implementation: `sap f xs = [ pre ++ [f x] ++ post | (pre, x:post) <- zip (inits xs) (tails xs) ]`

Comment: You might ask -- what about this function on things other than lists?  And if you thought about it long enough, you might start uncovering [this beautiful result](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.8611)

Comment: @Bergi I am calling it a _primitive_ for lack of something better, just to distinguish it from my function argument, `fn`.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner  Thanks. Isn't the return type of `zippers` a list, like  [([a], a, [a])] ?

Comment: @Luqui Thanks. I can vaguely perceive the kinship with the derivative of a product of functions. Long enough indeed :-)

Comment: @jpmarinier Oh my goodness yes. What an embarrassing mistake to have made, good catch!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like the simplest version of this is direct recursion:

```
sap :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [[a]]
sap _ [] = []
sap f (x:xs) = (f x : xs) : map (x:) (sap f xs)
```

One possible exploration of this is as a [paramorphism](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.1.3/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#v:para), which gives access to the recursive result and the unprocessed remainder together.

```
sap f = para step where
    step Nil = []
    step (Cons x (xs, rest)) = (f x : xs) : map (x:) rest
```

(Not checked, might have silly errors)

I don't see that as a huge improvement though. I don't see any deep insights in that decomposition of recursion from the problem itself.

For that, well...  I've used [`holesOf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.18.1/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#v:holesOf) for a generalized version of this in the past.

```
sap :: Traversable t => (a -> a) -> t a -> [t a]
sap f = map (peeks f) . holesOf traverse
```

Now that definitely says *something*. It has generalized the type to work on all instances of `Traversable`. On the other hand, the theoretical chunks involved were so overpowered for the end result that I'm not sure what it actually is that it says.  On the third(?) hand, it looks pretty.

Comment: You should probably note that `Nil` and `Cons` come from the type family `Base` used by `para`, and `para` has (specialized) type `(ListF ([], a) -> a) -> [] -> a` here.

Comment: Yes, direct recursion gives a solution that is compatible with unlimited lists, unlike my foldr-based one. And without decreasing performance significantly. Thanks ! Hopefully I will get to understand paramorphisms later in my exploration of Haskell.

Comment: @jpmarinier that paramorphism example is probably a bit opaque due to that library's generality. You could work with a function like `listPara :: r -> (a -> [a] -> r -> r) -> [a] -> r` instead. It's a very slight modification of `foldr`, as paramorphisms and catamorphisms (like `foldr`) are very closely related. Given that, you'd have `sap f = listPara [] (\x xs rest -> (f x : xs) : rest)`.

Comment: Lenses. What else could be the answer :-)

Answer (score 5):

> Or is there a way to write it that is so short and simple that it does not even deserve to be a separate function, putting it below the so-called Fairbairn threshold?

This. The functionality is rarely needed, and the `(a -> a)` argument doesn't make for a very generic application.

A short and simple implementation can be achieved with list recursion:

```
sap :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [[a]]
sap _ []     = []
sap f (x:xs) = (f x:xs):((x:) <$> sap f xs)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it exists anywhere, although proving it negatively is of course impossible.. Another way to write `sap`, which I would probably prefer over using `foldr`,

```
sap f ls = zipWith (alterWith f) [0..] (iterate ls)
  where alterWith f i ls = take i ls ++ f (ls !! i) : drop (i+1) ls
```

`alterWith` is available as `adjust` in https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fft-0.1.8.6/docs/Math-FFT-Base.html#v:adjust, but I would very much not bring something so heavyweight in for that function. I often have something like `alterWith` defined in a project already, though, and if so that allows `sap` to be elided in favor of the call to zipWith above.

Answer (score 1):

Exploiting `Data.List.HT.splitEverywhere`:

```
import Data.List.HT

sap :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [[a]]
sap f xs = [ pre ++ f x : post | (pre,x,post) <- splitEverywhere xs]
```