# expand list of lists by adding element once to every list

Tags: list, haskell

I implement function which adds an element once to every list of a list.

example:

```
f :: a -> [[a]] -> [[[a]]]
f 7 [[1],[2],[3]]
[[[7,1],[2],[3]],[[1],[7,2],[3]],[[1],[2],[7,3]]]
```

I start with this solution:

```
f :: a -> [[a]] -> [[[a]]]
f e xs = ((\n -> (\(x,l)-> if x==n then e:l else l) <$> zip [1..] xs)  <$> [1..length xs])
```

Can you please provide some more nice implementations of this function?

Comment: Some generalization discussed here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/59655402/11282404](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59655402/11282404) with `f e xss = sap (e:) xss`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement this with recursion. As base case we consider an empty list:

```
f _ [] = []
```

for non-empty lists `(x:xs)` we can use the first item, which is the first sublist. We thus can produce a list where we prepend the first sublist `x` with the element `e`, followed by the remaining items `xs`, so `(e:x) : xs` is the first item. For the remaining items we recurse on the tail of the list `xs` and will for each sublist prepend this with the sublist `x`:

```
f e (x:xs) = ((e:x) : xs) : map (x:) (f e xs)
```

so putting these together gives us:

```
f :: a -> [[a]] -> [[[a]]]
f _ [] = []
f e (x:xs) = ((e : x) : xs) : map (x:) (f e xs)
```

Answer (score 4):

Write `splits` which gives all possible ways of splitting a list

```
splits :: [a] -> [([a], [a])]
splits xs = zip (inits xs) (tails xs)
```

for example

```
> splits "abc"
[("","abc"),("a","bc"),("ab","c"),("abc","")]
```

and using it write a function that operates on each element of a list

```
onEach :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [[a]]
onEach f xs = [ys ++ f z : zs | (ys, z:zs) <- splits xs]
```

like this

```
> onEach toUpper "abc"
["Abc","aBc","abC"]
```

and now `f` is just

```
f :: a -> [[a]] -> [[[a]]]
f x = onEach (x:)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer of David Flercher with onEach :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [[a]] very interesting, [I do some generalization](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OD_lNIPp7w) with typeclass, I think this is usefull when we need some versions of objects mutated in one parameter..:

```
class Eachable e where
  each :: (a -> a) -> e a -> [e a]
```

Now we can each on different types for example on Lists:

```
instance Eachable [] where
  each _ [] = []
  each g (x:xs) = ((g x) : xs) : map (x:) (each g xs)

 each (+1) [1,2,3]
[[2,2,3],[1,3,3],[1,2,4]]
```

and Trees

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving Show

instance Eachable Tree where
  each _ Empty = []
  each g t@(Node l a r) = (\i -> e g 1 i t) <$> [1..count t] where
                                                               e _ _ _ Empty = Empty
                                                               e g c i (Node l a r) = Node l' a' r' where
                                                                                                      a' = if c==i then g a else a
                                                                                                      l' = if c==i then l else e g (c+1) i l
                                                                                                      r' = if c==i then r else e g (c+(count l)+1) i r
count Empty = 0
count (Node l _ r) = 1 + count l + count r

tr = Node (Node Empty 1 Empty) 2 (Node Empty 3 Empty)
each (+1) tr
[Node (Node Empty 1 Empty) 3 (Node Empty 3 Empty),Node (Node Empty 2 Empty) 2 (Node Empty 3 Empty),Node (Node Empty 1 Empty) 2 (Node Empty 4 Empty)]
```

and others:

```
data Animal a = Animal {speed::a,size::a,smart::a} deriving Show

instance Eachable Animal where
  each g (Animal sp sz sm) = [Animal (g sp) sz sm, Animal sp (g sz) sm, Animal sp sz (g sm)]

each (+1) $ Animal 1 1 1
[Animal {speed = 2, size = 1, smart = 1},Animal {speed = 1, size = 2, smart = 1},Animal {speed = 1, size = 1, smart = 2}]
```